# Html.fromHtml does not removes <!-- comments -->

Tags: android, html, comments

I am currently parsing some HTML code and I would like to put in a Textview. (Webview is too much, I just want something very simple).

The `Html.fromHtml(mySource)` is great and working fine.
This line makes my text turn in colors, bold, italic, etc...

Unfortunately, it has some inconvenients, it does not remove the comments.

Do you have any solution other than using a WebView?

[image]

Comment: If they are inside a `<script>` element, then they are data, not comments. `<script>` is defined as containing CDATA, so characters with special meaning in HTML (except `</`) don't have that meaning there.

Comment: You are totally right... Thank a lot for this information!

Comment: However, since `Html.fromHtml()` cannot interpret `<script>` elements, either, you still need to remove those from the HTML. `Html.fromHtml()` is not a terribly sophisticated converter, so for HTML "in the wild", you may have to do some cleanup first.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right and your answer is accepted! Removing the first <script> occurence is enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comments yourself before passing the string to `Html.fromHtml()`. Whether you use a regular expression or an HTML parser is up to you, though [this gentleman has an opinion on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Hi, I am currently having the same problem. I'm not sure what to use to remove the comments. I'm using something like this String finalText = original.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""); to remove the comments but if I do this before Html.fromHtml(), it removes all of my text!